# purpose of the public directory in a ruby app?

Tags: ruby

I'm really new to ruby.  I just installed phusion passenger and it's working with apache2 on Ubuntu.

I've successfully followed this tutorial:
https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_tutorial_example_writing_and_deploying_a_hello_world_rack_application

What I'm wondering about is what the public directory is for?  I tried putting a `home.ru` which simply had `puts "hello world"` .  When I did that, going to my browser at `http://localhost:81/home.ru` printed `puts "hello world"` instead of `hello world`.  Is the public directory meant for server side scripts at all?  If so, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: A Rack application needs a bit more than a single `puts` statement. You might want to look at using [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) as a really simple way to get started.

Comment: Ruby apps don't have public directories. Ruby-based Rails, and other web-apps using frameworks, CAN have public directories. Ruby is the language used to implement the other things. It's important to make the distinction.

Comment: And, I second @tadman's suggestion to learn Sinatra. It's a great way to get your feet wet using a web-stack, without all the hassle of Apache, nginx, Passenger or Unicorn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `public` directory is for what we call *static files*. They are served as-is by the web server without any kind of processing, and are usually cached by the browser.

For example, if you wanted to make a web page without any kind of dynamic content, you could simply drop your HTML and CSS files there and they would be directly accessible, just as your `home.ru` file was.

[Here's documentation for `Rack::Static`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/Rack/Static).

Comment: It also has the advantage of providing a strict separation between *code* and *content*, something other systems often heavily blur. This reduces the risk of your application source code leaking out due to a misconfigured server, or from people poking around by URL guessing and grabbing configuration files.